# Calculating sum in MongoDB and C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to calculate sum of a field in mongodb via C# driver, While meeting a certain condition and i don't have a clue how to work this out. 
What i need would be something like this:

```
var collection = Db.GetCollection<T>(key);
var sumValue = collection.Find(new QueryDocument("Checked", true))
                         .Aggregate(new BsonDocument ("$Sum", "Debit"));
```

But I don't know how to make this work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to calculate locally after retrieve the results, you have to use Aggregation Framework. Please, check the sintax, because I haven't tested it.

```
var match = new BsonDocument 
                { 
                    { 
                        "$match", 
                        new BsonDocument 
                            { 
                                {"Checked", "true"}                             
                            } 
                    } 
                };


var group = new BsonDocument 
                { 
                    { 
                        "$group", 
                        new BsonDocument 
                            { 
                                {"_id", new BsonDocument {"_id","$_id"}},
                                {"sum", new BsonDocument {"$sum","$Debit"}
                            } 
                    } 
                };

var pipeline = new[] {match, group }; 
var result = coll.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

[Here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c/) you have more examples.